# Matrix Calculation getting unauthorized for token server

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to get a token from the token server in C# and keep getting.

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

For oauth_consumer_key I'm using the ACCESS KEY ID

I have signed up for the free account.

Comment: I'm getting 

{"errorId":"ERROR-fa42e285-41f4-4189-844b-d4556766d555","httpStatus":401,"errorCode":401300,"message":"Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong.","error":"invalid_client","error_description":"errorCode: '401300'. Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong."}

Do you have an example of SHA 256 OAuth1.0 signature header in C#

Comment: this is my second error. I still need help with SHA 256 signing header.

I used postman with my client secret and got a token back but when i try to use the token in postman i get the following. { "error": "Forbidden", "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access" }

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind this error code is the **missing grant_type** value in request body.

**URL**

https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token

**The request body must contain:**

```
grant_type=client_credentials
```

**The request header must contain**

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Authorization: OAuth 1.0

```
oauth_consumer_key="<Access Key id>",
oauth_Consumer Secret="<Access Key secret>",
oauth_signature="<Signature>",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",
oauth_version="1.0"
```